# JavaScript object literal notation is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7. I am trying to get a handle on how namespacing should work. I can get some parts of to work, but not totally as I expect it to work. I expect that when the form element is typed in, the function checkPasswordForm will fire and alert the value of the field.

I have this form element.

```
<input type='text' id='Password'>
```

I expect that this code will create a namespace, crate an object, and create a function.

```
// SET NAMESPACE
var nsPASS = {

$Password: $('#Password'),

checkPasswordForm: function() {
    var Password = $Password.val();
    alert(Password);
}

};
nsPASS.$Password.keyup(nsPASS.checkPasswordForm);
```

This code doesn't run though. I get an error saying that $Password is not defined.  I modified the code a thousand different ways to get it to work. The version below works as I expect it to. It seems like more code than necessary to accomplish the task.

```
// SET NAMESPACE
var nsPASS = {

$Password: $('#Password'),

init: function() {
    $Password = $('#Password');
},

checkPasswordForm: function() {
    var Password = $Password.val();
    alert(Password);
}

};

nsPASS.init();
nsPASS.$Password.keyup(nsPASS.checkPasswordForm);
```

In the second example, if I remove nsPASS.init(), the code breaks. If I remove Password: $('#Password') the code breaks.

Can I define objects and then use them immediately in functions? Why does the first example work, but the second doesn't?

Comment: In the second example your `init` function defines a global variable `$Password`, it doesn't set the `$Password` property of the object.

Comment: variables & properties are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does not have namespaces, but only objects. If you have some value on a property of an object, you can't just use the property name like a variable, you will always need to address it via the object.

> In the second example, if I remove nsPASS.init(), the code breaks. If I remove Password: $('#Password') the code breaks.

That's because the one is an implicitly global variable (assigned in the `init` function, used in the `checkPasswordForm` function) - the other is the property of your `nsPass` object (initialized in the object literal, used in the `nsPASS.$Password.keyup(…)` call). So change it to

```
var Password = nsPass.$Password.val();
```

If you are writing functions that are always called in context of the namespace object (as methods), you could use the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) as a reference to the object. Yet, your particular function will be called as an event handler, so its context is the `#Password` input itself. You can easily change it to

```
var Password = $(this).val(); // or shorter: this.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Go back to the first block of code you used. You should be using this:

```
var Password = nsPASS.$Password.val();
```

That's the thing with objects like that, you have to always remember to specify where to look for the variable ;)